# Enable OIDs to Postgres Table after it is created

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to add OIDs to a Table with an ALTER statement?

EDIT: I should add I am using PG 8.3, and 8.3 manual does not list that option

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Why do you think you need it? OIDs are deprecated and shouldn't be used. And you shouldn't use 8.3 anyway. It will soon be retired.

Comment: OIDs have been deprecated as (invisible) system column for tables. Many other uses of OIDs are unaffected by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have your answer right there in the [manual for PostgreSQL 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-altertable.html):

> Note that there is no variant of `ALTER TABLE` that allows OIDs to be
>   restored to a table once they have been removed.

So the answer is **no**.

`SET WITH OIDS` was implemented shortly thereafter [with version 8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altertable.html).

But I can't think of a good reason to do that. OIDs in a user table, that was a broken concept to begin with. Good riddance.

Answer (score 7):

With postgresql 9.2:

```
ALTER TABLE "myTable" SET WITH OIDS;
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In less time than it takes to type your question you could have gone to the manual, and looked at the page for "ALTER TABLE"

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

The answer is yes, but that was a boring question.

An interesting question is why you think you want them? I'm 90% sure that you really don't.

Comment: I did go there, and for some reason when when I did "Ctrl+f" for OID, I only saw the 'without OID' option. Thanks

Comment: I would like to correct myself. I am using Postgres 8.3, and the 8.3 manual does not show the 'With OID' option http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

If OIDs are out of favour these days, you may wish to use alternative methods to add an auto-populated, auto-incrementing unique ID column such as:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table
ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Just note that this query will append a new column to the right of the table (some users like having their unique ID/pk on the left for aesthetics!)